# Name of parent category with parent_id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a quiz question and have hit a wall on how to solve the problem. The problem is as follows:

"Write a SQL query that lists all film categories by category_id, the category's name (called category) and the parent category's name (called parent), ordered alphabetically by the category's name."

The entity Category has a category_id, name and parent_cat(which is the id of another category)

This is the query that i have so far:

```
SELECT A.category_id, A.name AS category, (SELECT B.name WHERE A.parent_cat=B.category_id AND A.parent_cat IS NOT NULL) AS parent
FROM "Category" A, "Category" B
WHERE A.parent_cat IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY A.name
```

Unfortunately this is returning duplicate instances of the category with some of the instances having NULL values for "parent"

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.category_id, A.name AS category,  B.name AS parent
FROM "Category" A JOIN "Category" B ON A.parent_cat=B.category_id
WHERE A.parent_cat IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY A.name
```